# How to avoid getters in aggregate internal collection?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to follow the advice whereby "using getters/setters in your classes is evil".  So, say I have the aggregate class `Invoice` with the following signature:

```
public class Invoice{
    ISet<Line> _lines;
    public void ChangeLineAmount(int LineId, double newAmount){
               //Your answer here
           }
    }
```

How I can find the specific line for the change, if the `Line` class has no getters?

Comment: And the downvote is for?

Comment: just read your question have you looked at this MSDN Guidelines on Collections http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I just read it.  I'm not exposing my collection to the outside world, so I don't get your point, except for the naming conventions, may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason behind phrase "using getters/setters in your classes is evil" in a matter of DDD is that getters and setters are not representing your UL(ubiquitous language) usually and are leading to anemic entities. But if in your UL there is something like "I need amount of that line", then you can create getter but name it according to UL, like: `invoice.lineAmount(lineId)`.

Inside of method you can simply access property as CharlesNRice already answered. If you feel that you will need any special treatment for reading/setting lines, then you can create private getter to use it inside of domain logic methods.

**UPDATE:**

Getters and setters were needed in the first place because later in the project you could've want to add some additional validation/converting before setting/getting a property, without it you would have to find every piece of code that is accesing property and change it. With getter/setter you access property in one place so you change code in one place - much easier to maintain. But since in DDD you must use only domain logic methods, then you don't access your properties directly anywhere outside of given entity, so you also don't have to use getters and setters. Your domain methods like `invoice.lineAmount(lineId)` are actually working just like getters, but are going along with UL so they are ok. You would consider to create real getters/setters for internal use if you see that you are accesing property in few places in your entity class.

Comment: So, the advice must be "getters and setters are evil, unless actually required".  May be they can be internal to reduce his use to the aggregate wich they belongs?

Comment: The original statement seems to come from an 11 year old JavaWorld article.  I've read the article and it reads like a knee-jerk rant to the over misuse of 'getters' and 'setters'.  In DDD terms, I can't personally see anything wrong with using a 'getter' to expose a value that you have designed to be publicly exposed.

Answer (score 3):

- In "vanilla" DDD, it is recommended to avoid having direct setters (or getters of mutable collections) and make *domain operations explicit* instead. Use intention-revealing, ubiquitous language-compliant, invariant enforcing behaviors (methods) to mutate your entities wherever possible. However, in this approach entities are where you read data from as well, they have to expose their state for readers, so I can't see how you could do without getters.
- The CQRS(+ES) flavor of DDD would have a read model where you can obviously access everything you want with getters, and aggregates whose state you can only change via commands. Since all reads are done through ancillary read model objects and all writes through commands, you don't need getters or setters *on your external-facing aggregate roots* but roots themselves must be able to change entities inside their own aggregate, which sometimes requires setters.

In any case, things are nowhere as simple as "using getters/setters in your classes is evil".

Answer (score -1):

_line is just a field if it doesn't have a getter or setter.  If you add them then it's a property. To get the line you would use it just like it was a property.

```
public class Invoice{
     ISet<Line> _lines;
     public void ChangeLineAmount(int LineId, double newAmount)
     {
        var line = _lines.FirstOrDefault(l=>l.LineId == LineId);
        if (line != null)
        {
            line.Amount = newAmount;
        }
     }
}
```

I think it's personal opinion if "using getters/setters in your classes is evil".  I don't personally feel that way.